# Oreo - disable programmatically " your app" is running

Tags: android, kotlin, service, push-notification, android-8.0-oreo

Is there anyway to hide/disable programmatically from notification bar that notification that says "your app is running"? It looks really uncomfortable to my users.

I know it would appear becase i am using a sticky service, but I really need it. Hope somebody could help me

Comment: You can not do this . Since you are using a Foreground Service .

Comment: make custom notification that will be friendly for users. that's all that you can do in this situation

Comment: @HeyAlex Do you have any example of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only options I had was to migrate to [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client). Android OS force you to do that in order to improve the user experience and manage resources.